# inArray mongoose ObjectID

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongoose

I have this model:

```
var HuntGroupSchema = new Schema({
    name        : { type: String, required: true }
    ,domain     : { type: ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Domain' }
    ,members    : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
    ,email      : { type: String, unique: true}
    ,pin        : { type: Number, default: 0}
    ,extension  : { type: Number, required: true}
    ,timescheme : { type: ObjectId, ref: 'TimeScheme'}
    ,ddi        : { type: String}
});
```

and have this data

```
db.huntgroups.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50373487947749f0370000b0"), "ddi" : "01376xxxxxx", "domain" :      ObjectId("502807e9b9e737036d000018"), "email" : "julian@dotr.com", "extension" : 3001,     "members" : [ ObjectId("50376767b5c99cd862000003") ], "name" : "test22", "pin" : 1234 }
```

and this test always returns -1

```
// req.params['member'] === '50376767b5c99cd862000003'
var member_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params['member']);

console.log($.inArray(member_id, huntgroup.members));
```

can anyone tell me why ?

Warning: I am a newbie at mongoose, jquery and javascript, so go gentle ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `$.inArray` is only checking for reference equality on the ObjectId objects.

To compare the *values* of the ObectIds instead you'd need to use the `equals` operator of `ObjectId` by doing something like the following:

```
huntgroup.members.forEach(function(member) {
    if (member.equals(member_id)) {
        // Yes, member_id is contained in the array
    }
});
```

Comment: oh. I was confused by jQuery's definition:

jQuery.inArray() : Search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).

I thought that the "value within an array" meant exactly that :) 

I'll try your method instead.

thanks !

Comment: @user1542325 For primitive types like number, boolean and string, `inArray` compares their values, but not for reference types like `ObjectId`. http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_04.htm